# Explain this query in mysql

Tags: mysql, datediff

Can someone explain this query to me?

```
SELECT OPEN_DATETIME,
  DATEDIFF(OPEN_DATETIME, '2016-12-13 23:59:59') AS Aging
FROM batch
WHERE DATEDIFF(OPEN_DATETIME,'2016-12-14 23:59:59')>20;
```

**Output**

```
+------------------------+-------+
| OPEN_DATETIME          | Aging |
+------------------------+-------+
| 2017-01-26 16:28:41    |    44 |
| 2017-01-25 16:32:48    |    43 |
| 2017-01-27 02:00:00    |    45 |
+------------------------+-------+
```

I understand `datediff()` mean to get the number of difference days between two dates on MySQL. But I just don't understand why it needs two `datediff()` in this query?

Comment: The select and predicate are evaluated independently (aggregate functions are verified based on group by clause though).  Said another way, anything you "do" in the select statement isn't visible in the where clause.  If you were insistent on only having one function call you could wrap this.  SELECT dt, Aging from (SELECT OPEN_DATETIME as dt,
  DATEDIFF(OPEN_DATETIME, '2016-12-13 23:59:59') AS Aging FROM batch) WHERE Aging > 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second part of the query:

```
SELECT OPEN_DATETIME, DATEDIFF(OPEN_DATETIME, '2016-12-13 23:59:59') AS Aging
FROM batch
WHERE DATEDIFF(OPEN_DATETIME,'2016-12-14 23:59:59')>20;
```

In the `WHERE` clause:

```
DATEDIFF(OPEN_DATETIME,'2016-12-14 23:59:59')>20;
```

Uses the `DATEDIFF()` function again to limit results where it is over 20 days as you can't use `Aging > 20` as the alias is only defined in the query.

To use the `Aging` alias, and only use `DATEDIFF()` once, you could use:

```
SELECT a.* FROM (
SELECT OPEN_DATETIME, DATEDIFF(OPEN_DATETIME, '2016-12-13 23:59:59') AS Aging
FROM batch) a
WHERE a.Aging > 20
```

**EDIT**

Or as Eric answered you can use the `HAVING` clause to select an alias.

Answer (score 2):

I belive this should work without a double diff, just use HAVING on the alias.

```
SELECT OPEN_DATETIME,
DATEDIFF(OPEN_DATETIME, '2016-12-13 23:59:59') AS Aging
FROM batch
HAVING Aging >20;
```

Comment: You have +1 from me, this answer is correct and **having** tried it, it works.

Comment: I get different result

Comment: And what do you get?

Comment: I get more than 3 rows.

Comment: What is the aging for each row? > 20 ?